# How to optimize the searching of an unsorted array?

Tags: c++, optimization

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);

long long int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

int q, b;
cin >> q;

for(int j = 0; j < q; j++)  //Number of Queries
{
    cin >> b;

    int count = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < n; z++)
        if(b == arr[z])
            count++;

    if(count  == 0)
        cout << "NOT PRESENT" << "\n";
    else
        cout << count << "\n";
}
```

Here is a simple problem I was solving. It's a program meant to check the number of occurrences of a particular integer in an array. The array is not sorted.

The testing application is feeding the program with an input array of size 10000041 with 100000 queries and wants to finish the execution in 0.1 seconds.

For context, it takes the program 0.106354 seconds to execute with array size 10000 and number of queries 10000 on the testing application.

I know that these types of questions are not liked by the SO community but I have searched every resource I know of and could not find the solution.

Comment: This might be a good question for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use better data structure, linke `unordered_map`

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am being provided with the size of the array beforehand.

Comment: Also please learn how to write and use better variable naming. What is `b` supposed to be? What is it used for? When showing code for others, it helps a lot if you not only explain what your algorithm is supposed to do (and why you're doing it the way you're doing it) but also use good naming.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Will keep that in mind next time. Actually these variable names were provided by the question itself so I decided to stick with it.

Comment: You get the size of `arr` at *run-time*. Then you use a VLA which is an extension of *some* compilers. Use e.g. `std::vector<int> arr(n);` instead.

Comment: Well then show us the question. For competetive sites and online judge problems, always include a link to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry for the trouble, but can you please tell how will using a vector help if I create a fixed size array during run time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just curious, In the link you have shared there an example. Function accepts `n` as a size of array and array is declared as `int arr[n];` is that recommented or good to use?

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri So should I post such types of question at code-review? Can you please also please tell me how to decide where to post my question the next time?

Comment: `int arr[n]` is a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It's allowed in C. C++ doesn't have it. In C++ arrays must be created at *compile time*. But some compilers (most notably GCC) add it as a ***non-portable** extension*. You should not use those. Instead the definition using `std::vector` is portable and the way to have an "array" whose size is set at run-time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for replying to my queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to precompute the occurences of each number, and you can do it by using a `map` container:

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);

long long int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];
map <int, int> cnt;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
    cnt[arr[i]]++;
}
int q, b;
cin >> q;

for(int j = 0; j < q; j++)  //Number of Queries
{
    cin >> b;

    int count = cnt[b];

    if(count  == 0)
        cout << "NOT PRESENT" << "\n";
    else
        cout << count << "\n";
}
```

To optimize further you can use the `unordered_map` container as mentioned in the comment by @Mayur.

Comment: why not `unordered_map`?

Comment: @Mayur That also works, I wrote the first one that came to my mind

Comment: @NiVeR Thanks for providing the solution. I am currently not familiar with maps so I will try to understand it. Your program executed in 0.106016 seconds in the testing application.

Comment: @harshit54 Just have a read, they are not something fancy, at least when it comes to using them :)

Comment: @harshit54 Could you show us that testing application with 100k queries? Are you sure that the lookups are not optimized away? The runtimes are suspiciously almost equal.

Comment: @DanielLangr [Here](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/aarambh2/problems/b73e02700e-input-b73d9be.txt.clean.txt?Signature=MzcNDiL5f5slE%2BiPTIFMKzX%2Fh94%3D&Expires=1551951064&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI6ICDAQTL3Q6ZBKA) is the input file they were feeding.

Comment: @DanielLangr [Here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/memorise-me/) is the problem statement.

Comment: @harshit54 I meant the code, not only data. How do you measure runtime? What are you doing with the query results?

Comment: @DanielLangr Sorry for the late reply. The website itself gave me the [test results](https://imgur.com/a/zzvZAGE).

Comment: @DanielLangr Input #5 was terminated before completion and therefore that runtime is useless.

Comment: @harshit54 I just completed the whole test in 0.55 sec, however, I don't like this kind of tests, since the results depend mostly on the efficiency of parsing numbers from input streams. Namely, without that _sync-with-stdio_  and _cin-tie-NULL_ hacks, the runtime exceeded the limit of 0,6 seconds. BTW, since the queried numbers are limited to [0,1000] interval, I used a plain array of 1001 elements to precalculate possible queried number occurences. Such a solution is also mentioned in comments. Also, you should have definitely included the test link in the question.

Comment: @DanielLangr This is my first test question on SO, but I will remember to post the question next time.

Comment: @DanielLangr Some of the question on the website mention explicitly mention **Use Fast I/O**. That's how I came to know about the hack too.

Comment: @DanielLangr I like your solution too. It's less space consuming